# multinested json python to df

Tags: python, json, dataframe, nested

I have a json response with productdetails of multiple products in this structure

```
all_content=[{'productcode': '0502570SRE',
  'brand': {'code': 'MJ', 'name': 'Marie Jo'},
  'series': {'code': '0257', 'name': 'DANAE'},
  'family': {'code': '0257SRE', 'name': 'DANAE Red'},
  'style': {'code': '0502570'},
  'introSeason': {'code': '226', 'name': 'WINTER 2022'},
  'seasons': [{'code': '226', 'name': 'WINTER 2022'}],
  'otherColors': [{'code': '0502570ZWA'}, {'code': '0502570PIR'}],
  'synonyms': [{'code': '0502571SRE'}],
  'stayerB2B': False,
  'name': [{'language': 'de', 'text': 'DANAE Rot Rioslip'},
   {'language': 'sv', 'text': 'DANAE Red '},
   {'language': 'en', 'text': 'DANAE Red rio briefs'},
   {'language': 'it', 'text': 'DANAE Rouge slip brasiliano'},
   {'language': 'fr', 'text': 'DANAE Rouge slip brésilien'},
   {'language': 'da', 'text': 'DANAE Red rio briefs'},
   {'language': 'nl', 'text': 'DANAE Rood rioslip'},
   .......]
```

what i need is a dataframe with for each productcode only the values of specific keys in the subdictionaries. for ex.

```
productcode synonyms_code name_language_nl
0522570SRE  0522571SRE    rioslip
```

I've tried a nested for loop which gives me a list of all values of one specific key - value pair in a subdict.

```
for item in all_content:
synonyms_details = item ['synonyms']
for i in synonyms_details:
    print (i['code'])
```

How do I get from here to a DF like this

```
productcode synonyms_code name_language_nl
0522570SRE  0522571SRE    rioslip
```

Answer (score 0):

took another route with json_normalize to make a flattened df with original key in column

```
# test with json_normalize to extract list_of_dicts_of_list_of_dicts
# meta prefix necessary avoiding conflicts multi_use 'code'as key
df_syn = pd.json_normalize(all_content, record_path = ['synonyms'], meta = 'code', meta_prefix = 'org_')
```

result

```
code    org_code
0   0162934FRO  0162935FRO
1   0241472TFE  0241473TF
```

changed column name for merge with orginal df

```
df_syn = df_syn.rename(columns={"code": "syn_code", "org_code":"code"})
```

result

```
syn_code    code
0   0162934FRO  0162935FRO
1   0241472TFE  0241473T
```

merged flattened df with left merge based on combined key

```
df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_syn, how='left', left_on='code', right_on='code')
```

result see last column. NaN because not every product has a synonym.

```
code    brand   series  family  style   introSeason seasons otherColors synonyms    stayerB2B   ... composition recycleComposition  media   assortmentIds   preOrderPeriod  firstDeliveryDates  productGroup    language    text    syn_code
0   0502570SRE  {'code': 'MJ', 'name': 'Marie Jo'}  {'code': '0257', 'name': 'DANAE'}   {'code': '0257SRE', 'name': 'DANAE Red'}    {'code': '0502570'} {'code': '226', 'name': 'WINTER 2022'}  [{'code': '226', 'name': 'WINTER 2022'}]    [{'code': '0502570ZWA'}, {'code': '0502570PIR'}]    []  False   ... [{'material': [{'language': 'de', 'text': 'Pol...   [{'origin': [{'language': 'de', 'text': 'Nicht...   [{'type': 'IMAGE', 'imageType': 'No body pictu...   [BO_MJ] {'startDate': '2022-01-01', 'endDate': '2022-0...   {'common': '2022-09-05', 'deviations': []}  {'code': '0SRI1'}   nl  DANAE Rood rioslip  NaN
```

Next step is to get one step deeper to get the values of a list_of_lists_of_lists.

Suggestions for a more straightforward way? Extracting data like this for all nested values is quite timeconsuming.